# How to do do regex search on multiple lines?

Tags: swift, regex

I am searching for "- " in a string using regex and then replacing it with a bullet point.

If my string  is like this:

```
- Hello 1
```

It works. This is the result I get:

```
 . Hello 1
```

However, when my string is like this:

```
- Hello 1 - Hello 2  
- Hello 3
```

It doesn't work. This is what I get:

```
. Hello 1 - Hello 2
- Hello 3
```

This is the result I want:

```
. Hello 1 - Hello 2
. Hello 2
```

This is the function I am using:

```
    func applyBulletPointsFormat() {
        let matches = RegexPattern.bulletPointRegex.matches(mutableString as String)
        matches.reversed().forEach { formattedString in
            let newRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)
            replaceCharacters(in: newRange , with: "\u{2022} ")
        }
    }
```

This is my regex => "^\-\s(.*)"

This is the correct regex that i have created on www.regexr.com => "/^-\s(.*)/gm" . I dont know how to apply "/gm".

How do I apply multiline support to my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
let s = "- Hello 1 - Hello 2\n- Hello 3"
let result = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?m)^-(?=\\s)", with: "\u{2022}", options: .regularExpression)
print( result )
```

Output:

```
• Hello 1 - Hello 2
• Hello 3
```

**Details**

- `(?m)` - MULTILINE mode on
- `^` - start of a line
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=\s)` - the next char must be a whitespace (but the char is not placed into the match since it is a lookahead)